# Am I using the word "puzzle" well?

Tags: word-choice

I am adding a label in my app, and it contains the text "Add puzzle" or "Solve puzzle". I was thinking also about "exercise", "challenge".

This game / puzzle / exercise is an easy game, like tic-tac-toe, you can play with different users, but before it starts, need to set up. I need a title for this setup phase.

Would you use the word "puzzle" in an online game or a different one?

Comment: What's the question? Whether "Add puzzle" and/or "Solve puzzle" are correct usages? Or how to label the setup phase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer to use the *challenge* for game; *puzzle* is somehow diffrent. In written form (such as how you intend to use it – a web or app content), I think *challenge* is more appropriate than *puzzle*.